# How to set the alpha based on a column?

Tags: r, r-sp, r-sf, tmap

Consider this example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(tmap)

d <- data_frame(one = c(1,1,2,1,1,1,1),
                two = c(1,1,2,1,1,1,1))

std <- st_as_sf(d, coords = c('one', 'two'))

std %>% tm_shape() + tm_bubbles(alpha = 0.3)
```

[image]

You can see that point `(1, 1)` is darker because it appears 6 times in the data. Therefore, thanks to the `alpha` blending, these points add-up.

My problem is that I cannot store the dataset as it. What I have is only an aggregated version, like

```
d_agg <- d %>% group_by(one, two) %>% 
  summarize(count = n()) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 2 x 3
    one   two count
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     1     1     6
2     2     2     1
```

How can I reproduce the same exact chart as before, using `d_agg` and the corresponding `count` variable?

**Of course, re-creating the initial dataframe above is not feasible solution because I have too many points** (and some points are repeated too many times)

Just using:

```
std_agg %>% tm_shape() + tm_bubbles(col = 'count', alpha = 0.3)
```

does not work

[image]

Comment: Please add the packages you used in your code as well

Comment: You could recreate the original dataframe using `rep` rows n times?

Comment: no, that would be way too big. this is the issue.

Comment: I was thinking maybe you can assign `count == 1` with `grey100` then subtract `100` depending on `count` to create a darker color` e.g. `color <-  ifelse(count == 1, "grey100", paste0("grey", (100 - count + 1)))`

Comment: I don't know enough `sf/tmap` package to give a full answer. I am thinking, it must be possible take agg data row by row, expand then plot into variable (list), then keep appending following rows. At the end plot that list. This way we will only expand the data per group, not for all groups at once.

Comment: @Tung perhaps that is a good idea. However, count can take very large values as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, alpha is not (yet) an aesthetic, so it is not possible to do `alpha = "count"`.

My question: do you really need alpha? Probably not if you do not use the color aesthetic. In that case, your approach to use color to model alpha transparency was actually good, but just needs a little configuration:

```
std_agg %>% tm_shape() + tm_bubbles(col = 'count', style = "cont", 
    palette =  "Greys", contrast = c(.3, .7), legend.col.show = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! I wonder how can I use a palette like `viridis:magma` in this context?

Comment: The github version of tmap (will soon be tmap 2.0 on CRAN) supports viridis palettes natively: `palette = "magma"`. For tmap 1.x, just use `palette = viridis:magma(10)`

Comment: thanks but in this context why 10 instead of 100 or 1? i dont understand how this is mapped to the data above

Answer (score 1):

Here I show how to recreate your data frame `d` by using `dplyr`. Although it is not addressing your question about how to pass numeric value to the `alpha` argument in `tm_bubbles`, consider it as a workaround.

```
std_agg <- d_agg %>% 
  slice(rep(row_number(), times = count)) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c('one', 'two'))

std_agg %>% 
  tm_shape() + 
  tm_bubbles(alpha = 0.3)
```

[image]

In fact, this base R to expand the data frame is probably more intuitive.

```
d_agg[rep(1:nrow(d_agg), times = d_agg$count), ]
```

Comment: i appreciate but this cannot work because the resulting dataset would be too big

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ I know. This is just a workaround. Wait and see if some `tmap` experts can help.